# Filterable DataGrid with SubSonic

Tags: c#, subsonic

My goal is to create a DataGrid that uses a SubSonic object as its data source. The grid should have database-side paging and sorting, as well as columns that are intelligently filterable based on the data type of that column.

I actually have a fairly advanced prototype of the grid that does basically what it needs to. The problem is that in order to achieve the results, I had to include the SubSonic source in my solution, alter the generation templates for the data objects, and add entirely new templates for a super type that could serve paged, sorted, and filtered strongly typed collections. Adding those templates required that I also change the SubCommander code.

I'm dreading to upgrade SubSonic -- the changes I've made WORK, but they are about as tightly coupled and brittle as they can be.

Is there a more sane approach to changing and adding generation templates?

Alternatively, is there an out of the box solution to my DataGrid problem that I've just over looked?

Edit:

As much as I'd love to use the newer version, I'm dealing with legacy code and I can't. I need a solution for SubSonic 2.x

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Subsonic 3 solution, but have you seen Rob's screencast using Subsonic3,T4, and the jquery grid to do pretty much most of what you are asking above (paging,sorting,filtering)

http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/putting-the-ldquo-m-rdquo-back-in-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you need to do is use a Subsonic.Select .  If you create a method in your Framework that accepts all of your filters and the page number along with records per page you can add the filters that are needed and set the page and number of records. Check this out for examples.
http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/